# Cauchy Determinant with Absolute Values

Tags: determinant, absolute-value

This is perhaps a straightforward question but I'm a little confused. An $n\times n$ Cauchy matrix $A$ is a matrix with entries $$a_{i,j}=\frac{1}{x_i-y_j}$$ for $1\le i,j\le n$, where $x_i$ and $y_j$ are elements of a field $\mathcal{F}$, and $(x_i)$ and $(y_j)$ are injective sequences (they do not contain repeated elements; elements are distinct).

The determinant of $A$ is given explicitly as
$$\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(x_i-x_j)(y_j-y_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^n(x_i-y_j)}.$$

My question is this: what happens if one replaces the denominator of $a_{i,j}$ with its absolute value, in other words, does the determinant of the matrix $A'$ where $$a'_{i,j}=\frac{1}{|x_i-y_j|}$$ have a similar explicit evaluation?

Comment: The determinant of $A'$ is just $\pm$ the permanent of a Cauchy matrix, since we may swap columns/rows in order to grant $x_1<x_2<\ldots x_n$ and $y_1<y_2<\ldots<y_n$.

Comment: Right, thank you for pointing that out. As far as I know the permanent is a more complicated object than the determinant, I'm struggling to see how it may help in finding an explicit expression for the determinant of $A'$, perhaps you could elaborate a little further?